Probability Measures on Smooth Manifolds
Let $(M, O, \mathcal{A}, g)$ be an oriented Riemannian manifold. I am interested in defining a uniform probability measure on this manifold. However, the concept of "uniform" is less straightforward in this context compared to bounded intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, due to the absence of canonical global properties.
To address this, I propose the following definition:
Definition: Uniform probability measure on a Riemannian manifold.
Let $(M, O, \mathcal{A}, g)$ be an oriented Riemannian manifold, and let $\text{Isom}_g(M)$ denote its isometry group. Consider the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(O)$ generated by the open sets of $M$, so that $(M, \mathcal{B}(O))$ becomes a measurable space. A uniform probability measure is a probability measure $\mu: \mathcal{B}(O) \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies:
$$
\mu(S) = \mu(G(S)) \quad \forall S \in \mathcal{B}(O), \, \forall G \in \text{Isom}_g(M).
$$
In other words, a uniform probability measure is invariant under the action of the manifold's isometry group.
Given this definition, I have the following questions:

Does there exist a smooth top form $\omega$ on $M$ that corresponds to this measure, in the sense that:
$$
   \int_S \omega = \mu(S)
   $$
for all measurable subsets $S$ of $M$?

Can one derive a set of equations that this top form $\omega$ must satisfy? For instance, I suspect that $\nabla \omega = 0$ (where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection) might be a necessary condition.

Are there references or literature discussing such measures or the associated top forms on Riemannian manifolds?



For a compact manifold, the volume form will do, except you'll have to normalize it so that the total volume is $1$ in order to be a probability measure. It'll automatically be invariant under the isometry group. Is that the kind of thing you are looing for?
